# Invariant sets, La Salles invariance principle

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, lyapunov-functions

I got some trouble understanding La Salles invariance principle, more specifically this exercise where I want to investigate stability of the origin given system

$$\begin{cases} 
x'=-y-x^3\\ 
y'=x^5 
\end{cases}$$

I've chosen test function $V(x,y)=x^6+\alpha y^2$ which gives that $V_f(z)=-6x^8<0$ with the right choice of $\alpha$

Now to the part I don't understand. The solution from the course literature says that we check invariant sets of the system of the set $V_f^{-1}(0)$ (Where $V_f(x,y)=0$).
They come to the conclusion that the origin is the only invariant set on $V_f^{-1}(0)$, which I don't understand.

A invariant set is a set for which we start in, and stay in as time goes along. This, to me, means that the whole set $V_f^{-1}(0)$ should be an invariant set itself, since it is 0?

Would anyone mind explaining to me why the only invariant set in this set is the origin?

Thanks!

Comment: With that candidate for the invariant set now go back to the vector field.

Comment: It's **not** true that $-6x^8 <0 $ for all $(x,y) \neq (0,0)$! The set $V_f^{-1}(0)$ is the whole $y$-axis.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that! So, have I understood this correct that the solution from here on is that we want to find where the system is 0 on the $V_f^{-1}(0)$? So the only point in the system that satisfies this is the origin? Since that is the only place that we will stay at when starting at?

Comment: No, what you need to show is that if you start somewhere on the $y$-axis (except at the origin), then you leave the $y$-axis.